# How can I use swiftlint to enforce that every swift file must include a specified header values?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9.1, swiftlint

I wanted that every `*.swift` files must have the required texts.
Like so..
[image: Required header text on swift file]

If the developer forgets to add it or has inputted the wrong values `swiftlint` will give an error or warning upon compiling.

I have searched about `file_header` but somehow it doesnt work properly.
Here is my `swiftlint.yml` configuration
[image: Swiftlint configuration yml file]

Comment: What about [link1](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/creating-a-reusable-file-template-in-xcode-8c49830bc3a0) and [link2](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-custom-xcode-templates)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I wanted to use `swiftlint` on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use: `required_pattern`

```
    file_header:
      required_pattern: |
                        \/\/
                        \/\/  .*?\.swift
                        \/\/  (PROJECT_NAME.*?|Unit Tests)
                        \/\/
                        \/\/  (Created by .*? on .*?)
                        \/\/  Copyright © \d{4} COPY_RIGHT_NAME\. All rights reserved\.
                        \/\/
```

replace `PROJECT_NAME` and `COPY_RIGHT_NAME` with your values or change the pattern